# Placing a zero at coordinate center when plotting with Ticks -> None

Tags: plotting

I'd like to plot a certain function where only its qualitative progession shall be emphasized. Thus, using the `Ticks->None` option seems to be appropriate. However, I need to place a zero at the axes origin. My first choice was to put it in the epilog.
As a toy example, consider the code

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[(a + x)*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 4*Pi}, Ticks -> None, 
         Epilog -> Text[0, {-.1, .5}]
  ],{a, 1, 5}
]
```

As you can see, the zero gets closer to the x-axis as *a* increases and in my real case, the zero is striked out by the x-axis for some parameter values.

How can I place a zero to indicate the axis origin, such that it is independent of the function drawn? Ideally, the x-axis is only drawn for non negative *x* and a zero would be placed right left to the point *(0,0)*.

Comment: Do you need both axes? If you don't, you could use: `Manipulate[
 Plot[(a + x)*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 4*Pi}, Ticks -> {{0}}, 
  Axes -> {True, False},PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}}], {a, 1, 5}]`. The problem is "A tick label on the axes origin is not displayed" (alternatively, you could move the `AxesOrigin`)

Comment: Pinguin Dirk, nice idea! That actually solves another issue I'm having. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want can be had by using [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Offset.html) coordinates:

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[(a + x)*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 4*Pi},
  Ticks -> None, 
  Epilog -> Text[0, Offset[{-8, 8}, {0, 0}]],
  PlotRangePadding -> 1],
 {a, 1, 5}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A fast and dirty solution would be to freeze the Plotrange. For your example try: `PlotRange -> {{-.5, 10}, {-15, 15}}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid any manual placement of the zero by placing a single tick at the origin, similar to Pinguin Dirk's suggestion. For it to be displayed, you moreover need to make the plotrange start from zero in the x-direction:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[(a + x)*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 4*Pi}, Ticks -> {{}, {0}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, Automatic}], {a, 1, 5}]
```